# using buttons for changing font size for the whole website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, web, accessibility

i am trying to implement accessibility tools and i have managed to change the font size of a paragraph once the button has been clicked but i tried altering the code so that it will work on all the paragraph and it does not work

```
<script>

function myFunction()

{
 var p =document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // Find the element
p.style.fontSize="1.5em";          // Change the style
}
</script>

<button type="button" style="background: #ccc url(images/small.jpg);  padding: 0.3em 1em"   onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

this is how it worked before for just one paragraph but i am trying to more than one:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
x=document.getElementById("demo") // Find the element
x.style.fontSize="3.0em";          // Change the style
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the image via the `src` attribute versus CSS. When you use `src` the `alt` attribute becomes valid. Otherwise this `button` is not accessible.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), which is like an array, so you have to loop through them and apply the style to each element:

```
function myFunction() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].style.fontSize = "1.5em";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue in the first code block is that getElementsByTagName returns an nodeList of elements (which you can pretend is an array).  So you would need to do this:

```
var p =document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // Find the element
for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
  p[i].style.fontSize="1.5em";          // Change the style
  }
```

However, a better approach would be to define some css classes to do this job for you.

```
<style>
body { /*normal size*/
  font-size: 1em;
}

body.largeFont {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
</style>

<script>
function largeFont() {
  document.body.className="largeFont";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), which is _not_ an Array : (.